# Post request mysql with foreign keys?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, sequelize.js

I´m trying to create a post request that is suppose to check if the person posting the request is the person logged in and then posts the response. I have a table for the customer and a table for address, I want to make a post request to the address so that when the logged in user inserts an address their id will be stored as a foreign key in the address table. My address table looks like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Address = sequelize.define("Address", {
      address: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      city: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      postcode: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      country: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      }
    });
    return Address;
  };
```

and my customer table is like this:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Customers = sequelize.define("Customers", {
      firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      password: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
        validate: {
          notEmpty: true
        }
      },
      isAdmin: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        default: '0',
      }
    });
    Customers.associate = (models) => {
      Customers.hasMany(models.Address, {
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
  
      Customers.hasMany(models.Orderline, {
        onDelete: "cascade",
      });
    };
  
    return Customers;
  };
```

my post request is like this:

```
addressRouter.post(
    '/:id', isAuth,
    expressAsyncHandler( async (req, res) => {
    const {id, address, postcode} = req.params;
    const customer = await Customers.findOne({where: {id: id}})
    const custAddress = await Address.findOne({where: {address,postcode}})

    const shippingAddress = {
        address: req.body.address,
        city: req.body.city,
        postcode: req.body.postcode,
        country: req.body.country,
    }
    if (!customer) {
        res.status(401).send({
            message: "Customer Not Found",
        });
    }else if(custAddress){
        res.status(401).send({
            message: "Address already exist",
        });
    }else{
        Address.create(shippingAddress);
        res.send({
            id: shippingAddress.id,
            address: shippingAddress.address,
            city: shippingAddress.city,
            postcode: shippingAddress.postcode,
            country: shippingAddress.country,

        });
    }
})
```

please do not mind the isAuth function because that works I was able to update info for user with it. my Api for the post request looks like this:

```
export const shipping = async({address, city, postcode, country}) => {
    try{
        const {token} = getCustomerInfo();
        const response = await axios({
            url: `${apiUrl}/api/${id}`,
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type' : 'application/json',
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
            data:{
                address,
                city,
                postcode,
                country,
            },
        });
        if(response.statusText !== 'OK'){
            throw new Error(response.data.message);
        }
        return response.data;
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        return {error: err.response.data.message || err.message};
    }
};
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an association from 'Address' to `Customer`:

```js
Address.associate = (models) => {
      Address.belongsTo(models.Customer);
};

return Address
```

and of course indicate `customerId` in a newly created address:

```js
Address.create(shippingAddress);
        res.send({
            id: shippingAddress.id,
            address: shippingAddress.address,
            city: shippingAddress.city,
            postcode: shippingAddress.postcode,
            country: shippingAddress.country,
            customerId: customer.id
        });
```

Comment: thank you for you response, I´m getting a 500 error saying "WHERE "address" had invalid "undefined" value". do you know what might be causing this?

Comment: Please add the whole error description and stacktrace to your post (not in comments)

Comment: it literally just says that and with this message "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)". In the route when I remove this line " const custAddress = await Address.findOne({where: {address,postcode}}" it seems to work but it doesn't send the customerId to my database :/

Comment: Can you wrap `await Address.findOne({where: {address,postcode}})` with try/catch to find out what exact error occured?